# Can I use DocumentApp.openById() with read only permission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am creating a Google Apps Script add-on that is for a Google Spreadsheet, but it needs to be able to access the content of a separate Google Doc, which I am doing using [DocumentApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String)). I have given the script these [scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes):

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ]
```

But apparently, that's not enough. The script is telling me it needs the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents` permission to work properly. However, it seems excessive to give the add-on permission to edit ALL Google Docs files when it just needs to be able to view the content of one. Am I missing something? Is there a way to give it read-only access to a separate Google Docs file?

Here is the function I am using for testing, with most of the document ID censored out:

```
function getDoc() {
  var id = '1NLH----------------------------------------'
  var templateFile = DocumentApp.openById(id)
  var templateText = templateFile.getBody().getText()
  Logger.log(templateText)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether my proposal is the same direction of your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: "Can I use DocumentApp.openById() with read only permission?" Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the text data from Google Document using the following script.

  ```
    function getDoc() {
      var id = '1NLH----------------------------------------'
      var templateFile = DocumentApp.openById(id)
      var templateText = templateFile.getBody().getText()
      Logger.log(templateText)
    }
  ```
- You want to achieve this using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly` and Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, `DocumentApp.openById` of Document service is used, it is required to use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents`. It seems that this is the current specification. So, in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use Google Docs API instead of Document service. When Google Docs API is used, your script can be achieved using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly`.

When your above script is modified using Google Docs API, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). This script can work with only the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const documentId = "###"; // Please set the Document ID.

  const obj = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);
  const text = obj.body.content.reduce((s, c) => {
    if (c.paragraph && c.paragraph.elements) {
      s += c.paragraph.elements.map(e => e.textRun.content).join("");
    }
    return s;
  }, "");
  console.log(text)
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)

Comment: That's pretty cool.  It returns the entire document. I've never  used that API before. Thanks

Comment: Are you some kind of wizard? That worked perfectly, thank you so much! Now I just have to learn the API output so I can understand that better. Again, thanks! https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents

Comment: @Max Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.